# Applications of Hierarchical Dirichlet Process to Continuous Data

Tags: bayesian, hierarchical-bayesian, dirichlet-process

I read Yee Whye Teh et al.'s paper on [Hierarchical Dirichlet Process](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jordan/papers/hdp.pdf). In section 5, they show sampling algorithm using base distribution H and data distribution F.

One of their applications is HDP-LDA, which uses Dirichlet for H and Multinomial for F.

As a part of my application, I would like to cluster data on a multidimensional space that is supposed to follow Normal distribution. If it is on a two dimensional space, part of the data looks like this.

[image]

The figure above can be thought as a "document" in HDP-LDA and I have a lot of figures that have data points on similar but different coordinates.

If I want to cluster this data, can I use Normal distribution for H and F so that they are conjugate? Is there any way to use Dirichlet Process for continuous data?